# Projects containing version <unknown> deployment descriptors require XMI-format bindings or extensions files

Tags: eclipse, websphere-8

I am getting the following error

> Projects containing version <unknown> deployment descriptors require XMI-format bindings or extensions files.

But my web.xml says...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Also the facet appears to be 2.5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your `xmlns` is wrong since it is missing `http://`.  (Your `xsi:schemaLocation` is also wrong, but that's less important).  Here is a correct root element:

```
<web-app
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5"
>
  <!-- ... --->
</web-app>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me. I had looked at a previous SO suggestion that gave incorrect namespaces. I didn't realize it and just copy pasted.